# How can I have meta data to describe multiple employees on a single page using HTML?

Tags: html, metadata

I currently have a page for every employee with the following meta tags as an example

```
<meta name="cn" content="Angela"/>
<meta name="uid" content="angela"/>
<meta name="title" content="Manager"/>
<meta name="location" content="Room 1"/>
<meta name="telephoneNumber" content="12345" />
<meta name="manager" content="Maxim"/>
```

What I would like to do however is to have a single page with multiple employees but be able to describe the employees in a similar fashion. How can I achieve this using HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the metadata processing system you use, or expect to be used. Most `meta` tags with `name` attribute are write-only: you can write them as much you like, and nobody cares.

If you are just planning a metadata system (a definition of metadata structure and processing metadata), then you might consider using microdata and Schema.org vocabularies as defined by some major search engines. This will *probably not* make Google and friends process your metadata and utilize it in specialized searches (like they now have for places, recipes, books, etc.), but it *may* have such impact some day. In any case, they have put some effort in designing reasonable, useful formats for metadata.

For example, http://schema.org/Person describes a metadata system for personal information. It is rather verbose in markup, but just tolerably complicated. See also the general [description of microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#encoding-microdata).

Comment: Thanks Jukka. How does RDFa play a role in HTML metadata? Will it be compliant with search engines?